# Adding scale labels to levelplot's margins

Tags: r, plot, raster, r-raster, rastervis

I'd like to add label showing the `values` of `latitudinal zonal averages` to `levelplot's` gray `margin`. In the following example, the `min` and `max` values for `latitudinal means` are `286` and `751` respectively. Any suggestion on `adding an axis` with this information to the `margin`? 
[image]

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
levelplot(r, at=seq(100, 1850, by = 250))
# calculating the latitudinal means
rows <- init(r, v='y')
yAve <- zonal(r, rows, fun='mean',na.rm=TRUE)  
summary(yAve)
```

Comment: I get an error trying to run your code, also, make sure to list all packages you're using. In this case `raster` and `lattice`

Comment: `levelplot(r, at=seq(100, 1850, by = 250))` returns `no applicable method`

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the required libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `margin=list(axis=TRUE)` to add the min and max values to the margin.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
levelplot(r, at=seq(100, 1850, by = 250), margin=list(axis=TRUE))
```

You can change the color and fontsize of the margin labels using `gpar`.

```
library(grid)
levelplot(r, at=seq(100, 1850, by = 250), margin=list(axis=gpar(col = 'black', fontsize = 9)))
```

[image: Margin labels]

Comment: Great, that's much!

Comment: Is it possible to control the precision of the values? I'm getting 0.0018 at the low end. Zero is fine..